# Wordpress twenty-twenty three cover fixed background issue

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue with this website: [www.nymeia-akitas.at](http://www.nymeia-akitas.at)
We use the standard twenty-twenty three theme.
There is a cover with a fixed background and the image doesn't show up.

I hope someone can help fix this issue.

Thanks,
Mak

It works when changed to not fixed, but that is not a solution.
Didn't try much as I couldn't find any information that is connected to that theme and problem.